# Sublime Text 2 remove all Class items from entire project folder

Tags: css, regex, sublimetext2

We have taken over a previously designed website. We are going to rewrite all the CSS from scratch. The current website project has several 'class="stuff foo"' and tons of other classes.

Is there a way in Sublime Text 2 to REMOVE all item within all class elements?

**Example:**

```
<div id="BasicLogin" class="login 50per wide homepage">
```

**Cleaned to:**

```
<div id="BasicLogin" class=""> OR
<div id="BasicLogin">
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a project in Sublime Text and add all the folders you need to work with.

Use "Find > Find in files" to find/search in all open files and folders 
(they are the folders previously added to the project, and are shown in the sidebar)

Mark the "regular expression" option (icon .*).
Use the search pattern:

`\s+class="[^"]*"`

and an empty replace string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions

example

```
find: (\<div\ id\ \=\"BasicLogin\"\ class\=\")([a-z\ A-Z0-9]+)([\"\>]+)
replace: $1$3
```